# How to download images to my adapter from phpbyadmin fastly

Tags: android, image, listview

I am writing a social platform app. I am using PHPMyAdmin. My problem is: When I open my profile (activity ), my downloaded images are downloading too slowly or don"t.İf I open my activity layout, I see white paper. After 1-2 minutes, they loaded half. How can I fix it?

Here is my activity code AsyncTask :

```
 public class DownloadImageKullanici extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        String ID_res;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (!DownStop) {

                FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                File file = null;
                try {
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    String imageFileName = "MH_JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

                    ftpClient.connect(AConnect.Connect_image, 21);
                    ftpClient.login(AConnect.FTPKul, AConnect.FTPSifre);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    String remoteFile1 = "/" + URL[0];
                    Log.e("name", remoteFile1);
                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), imageFileName);

                    OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    ID_res = URL[1];
                    boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                    //Dosya indi log u.
                    Log.e("Dosya indi", String.valueOf(success));
                    outputStream1.close();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    File file_del = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), imageFileName);
                    file_del.delete();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return bitmap;
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // Set the bitmap into ImageView
            // image.setImageBitmap(result);

           /* ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
*/

            galeri_yedek.addAll(galeri);

            {
                //  galeri.clear();
            }
            ActKullanici.adaptorRes.addListItemToAdapter(new DgknRes(ID_res,result));


            // Close progressdialog
        }


    }
```

My logcat :

```
04-17 18:47:21.072 2488-7160/com.jmteknoloji.mypdym E/Dosya indi: false
04-17 18:47:21.646 2488-7160/com.jmteknoloji.mypdym E/name: /M_JPEG_20180417_131223.jpg
04-17 18:47:22.088 2488-7160/com.jmteknoloji.mypdym E/Dosya indi: true
04-17 18:47:22.508 2488-7160/com.jmteknoloji.mypdym E/name: /M_JPEG_20180417_131156.jpg
```

Comment: People typically use http servers to host images, not ftp. Then you could use Glide or Picasso libraries... Also, looks like you're storing passwords in your app, which is never a good idea

Comment: It's not clear what `FTPClient` is. Please add more info. Is it a 3rd party library? Custom code that you wrote?